# Solve the following contour integral (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Compute the following integral:
$$\int_{\delta D_1(0)} \frac{e^{z}}z dz $$

So I rewrote the formula in terms of $x$ and $y$ since $z = x + iy$
I got $$f(z) = \frac{e^xysin(y) + e^xxcos(y)}{x^2+y^2}+i\frac{e^xxsin(y) + e^xycos(y)}{x^2+y^2}$$

From here I wasn't 100% sure what to do, should I convert to polar and then go from there?

And just to double check does the notation $\int_{\delta D_1(0)}$ mean $\int_{-1}^1$? This particular notation confuses me a bit. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The integration bounds you ask about depend on your choice of parameterization. Also, do you know about the Cauchy Integral Formula?

Comment: $D_r(z_0)$ represents the disk of radius $r$ centered at $z = z_0$. So, $D_1(0)$ represents the unit disk. $\delta D_1(0)$ is the boundary of $D_1(0)$, i.e. the unit circle.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Ok that was what I thought too thanks for the verification

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\delta D_1(0)$ is the boundary of the unit disk, counter-clockwise oriented, the residue theorem gives:

$$\int_{\delta D_1(0)}\frac{e^z}{z}\,dz = 2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^z}{z},z=0\right)=2\pi i.$$

Comment: That makes sense thank you. In what way would the answer be different if the bounds were say $\delta D_2(0)$ ?

Comment: @jstar: the answer would be the same in that case. $z=0$ is the only singularity of $\frac{e^z}{z}$.